# Needing Array Formula Please

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am using this formula in Google sheets and it is running from cell CQ22:CQ605.  Just wondering if there is a fast maybe Array formula way of calculating all of this.  Help is much appreciated.

```
=IF(AND(INDIRECT("Data!E"&13+$F$7+ROW()-21)>=$CQ$17,INDIRECT("Data!E"&13+$F$7+ROW()-21)<=$CQ$16),INDIRECT("Data!E"&13+$F$7+ROW()-21),"")
```

Comment: So, if the INDIRECT("Data!E"&13+$F$7+ROW()-21) is NOT >= to $CQ$17 & <= $CQ$16 then we want it left blank.

Comment: What are the contents of data!e, f7, qc16 and cq17? This must clear first

Comment: Please share a sanitised copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(IF((INDIRECT("Data!E"&13+F7+ROW(A22:A605)-21)>=CQ17)* 
                  (INDIRECT("Data!E"&13+F7+ROW(A22:A605)-21<=CQ16),
  INDIRECT("Data!E"&13+F7+ROW(A22:A605)-21), )
```

Comment: It errored out, so I simplified it to this and it still only populates the cell CQ22 I put it in. I have all cells CQ22:CQ605 blank, so I am not sure what the problem is? 
 =ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("Data!E"&13+$F$7+ROW(A22:A605)-21))

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?